# Alsamixer not working no sound

Tags: linux, arch-linux

The sound is no more working on my machine.
before that I was running **mocp** my computer was **turned off accidently**

> when **I type alsamixer** as a **root** in **terminal** I get:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

> I did reinstall alsa-utils

Answer (score 3):

Similar thing happened with me yesterday, I tried:

```
alsactl init
```

and it started working. I think there is some issue with power manager which stops sound when some condition triggers.

Comment: alsactl init
alsactl: sysfs_init:48: sysfs path '/sys' is invalid

alsactl: init:1758: No soundcards found...